# Visual Studio 2012 cannot save my Sql Database in Asp.net Website

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express and have a razor c#.net project set up.

I have right clicked on AppData and added a Microsoft SQL database

Now I can see that it is there, I goto the Database Explorer and right click on Tables and click add table.

The table designer comes up and I make a few columns making sure "Id" remains primary key.

There is a table properties panel which I can't edit the name in as it is greyed out?
    When I save the table it makes me choose the location for the file, what file is this? The table or the database???
    If I save the SQL file in the app data part, It doesn't appear under the Tables folder any way.

Comment: Hi, I am experirncing the same problem. Have you solved it? Would you please let me know how to fix this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] 
Instead of saving the table, we should use update option. It will available at left hand top corner of table design view.

Refer above screenshot which highlighted the update.